# How to ignore a join when variable is null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having issues when I have multiple joins and when the variables passed to them are null. I'm wondering how to ignore the join when the value is empty.  I thought I could do it like this, but this doesn't bring me the correct results when any one of the params has a value and the rest do not.

```
@param1 int = NULL
,@param2 int = NULL
,@param3 int = NULL

SELECT t.ID,t.Col1 FROM Table t
 JOIN RelationalTable1 t1 ON (@param1 IS NULL) OR ( t1.ID1 = t.ID AND t1.ID2 = @param1 )
 JOIN RelationalTable2 t2 ON (@param2 IS NULL) OR ( t2.ID1 = t.ID AND t2.ID2 = @param2 )
 JOIN RelationalTable3 t3 ON (@param3 IS NULL) OR ( t3.ID1 = t.ID AND t3.ID2 = @param3 )
```

How can I make these Joins dissapear when their params are null?

Comment: How are the results not correct? Please provide an example. You can create one over at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: It returns 0 results when all params are emtpy or it doesn't return the data compounded when there's 1+ params not null.

Comment: You should write dymanic sql to handle this. You can't just ignore a join. If it wil ever only be 2 or 3 parameters you could write separate selects using the If construction, but more than 3 gets out of hand vey quickly and even three has an awful of of cases to handle manually.

Comment: this condition t1.ID1 = t.ID must be always present and it goes in AND with (@param1 IS NULL) OR (t1.ID2 = @param) (same thing about other 2 conditions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using the joins as filters, and you want to keep everything when the parameters are `NULL`.

My recommendation is to switch to `left outer join`:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Col1
FROM Table t LEFT JOIN
     RelationalTable1 t1
     ON (@param1 IS NULL) OR ( t1.ID1 = t.ID AND t1.ID2 = @param1 ) LEFT JOIN
     RelationalTable2 t2
     ON (@param2 IS NULL) OR ( t2.ID1 = t.ID AND t2.ID2 = @param2 ) LEFT JOIN
     RelationalTable3 t3
     ON (@param3 IS NULL) OR ( t3.ID1 = t.ID AND t3.ID2 = @param3 )
WHERE ((@param1 IS NULL) or (t1.ID is not null)) and
      ((@param2 IS NULL) or (t2.ID is not null)) and
      ((@param3 IS NULL) or (t3.ID is not null));
```

The `where` clause is saying "where the parameter is null or there is a match in the corresponding table".

I'm not sure if the parameter `IS NULL` is needed in the `on` clause.  It would generate additional multiple rows for each row in the additional tables.